# I can not write json model with aspjson

Tags: json, asp-classic

How to write the json below with **[aspjson](http://www.aspjson.com/)**:

```
[
  {
    "file_name": "xx",
    "user_name": "xxx",
    "action_date": "xxx",
    "action_text": "xxx",
    "user_profile_photo": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "file_name": "yyy",
    "user_name": "yyy",
    "action_date": "yyy",
    "action_text": "yyy",
    "user_profile_photo": "yyy"
  }
]
```

Comment: Please show what you tried so far.

Comment: Set oJSON = New aspJSON
With oJSON.data
.Add "file_name", "xxx"                      'Create value
end with
With oJSON.data
.Add "file_name", "yyy"   
end with
Response.Write oJSON.JSONoutput()

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
Dim oJSON : set oJSON = New aspJSON
oJSON.Data.Add 0, oJSON.Collection()
oJSON.Data(0).Add "file_name", "xxx"
oJSON.Data.Add 1, oJSON.Collection()
oJSON.Data(1).Add "file_name", "yyy"

Response.Write oJSON.JSONOutput()
```

Output:

```
[ { "file_name": "xxx" }, { "file_name": "yyy" } ]
```

Comment: If that works then could you mark it as the correct answer, it closes the question

Comment: Glad to help! I've been using aspJSON for several different projects over the past few months. I was greatly confused at first, but once you get used to it it's pretty dang cool.